# How can I automatically let vertices join in a block shape?

Tags: scripting

I generated a track of blocks,[image] and what I want to do is to have each block separately joined like this:[image]

Now the problem is that I have a really long track of these blocks, and want to do this automatically with a script or a plugin. Is that somehow possible? Sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `joined`?  In the first image it looks like the blocks are joined, in the sense one block's vertices on one end match the next block's vertices on opposite end.

Comment: Well the track is one object, but what I want is to separate all these points which make that block shape, and have these blocks as separate objects, instead of one big track. So I want each blocky shape like the picture above to be a separate object to export.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you have a modifier stack like below:

[image: modifier stack]

Make sure `Merge` is not selected in `Array` modifier.  Also note that I created a small gap between array elements (using an offset of `1.100`), but if `Merge` is not enabled gap should not be necesary.

### Separating Each Block

- You need to apply the modifiers, first `Array` then `Curve`. (order is important)
- Now you have a single mesh containing all the blocks.
- Go into `Edit Mode`.
- Choose `Mesh` -> `Separate` -> `By Loose Parts` in menu.
- Now you should have each block as a separate object.

Comment: When I added the modifiers, I got a duplication of the original. And the Separating didn't work, still have a full track. https://gyazo.com/6f16d6a2bd0c27349c0713e96dec26d1

Comment: Just adding modifiers on any object won't work.  I assumed you built a single block and used the combination of `Array` & `Curve` to create the track. How did you build the complete track?

Comment: I used a combining tool which generates a track using data from a specific game.

Comment: Okay. Please try `Separate` -> `By Loose Parts`.